# highlight matched pattern and a few more characters before and after the match using SED in Linux (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, highlight

I have two sets of columns of data in a file as shown below:

```
abc-pods-7c5576f85c-zl6g2         1/1     Running       0          5d11h             xyz-pods-fbc9fb4d9-547zd          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
abc-pods-5fb6fbcdbb-7v99v         1/1     Running       1          2d14h             xyz-pods-xc5576f85c-Xl6g2         0/1     Pending       0          5d11h
abc-pods-5fb6fbcdbb-n8hbn         0/1     Pending       2          5d10h             xyz-pods-xfb6fbcdbb-Xv99v         1/1     Running       1          2d14h
abc-pods-5fb6fbcdbb-qdtz6         1/1     Running       0          5d10h             xyz-pods-xfb6fbcdbb-X8hbn         1/1     Running       2          5d10h
abc-pods-5fb6fbcdbb-zn6pn         1/1     Running       2          5d10h             xyz-pods-xfb6fbcdbb-Xdtz6         1/1     Running       0          5d10h
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-2pq7t         1/1     Running       1          3d9h              xyz-pods-xfb6fbcdbb-Xn6pn         1/1     Running       2          5d10h
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-8zxfs         1/1     Running       0          27h               pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xpq7t         1/1     Running       1          3d9h 
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-fr6kc         0/1     Terminating   0          112d29h           pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xzxfs         0/1     Pending       0          27h  
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-gf7gn         1/1     Running       0          2d14h             pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xr6kc         1/1     Running       0          29h  
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-hs6b7         0/1     Pending       0          10h               pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xf7gn         1/1     Running       0          2d14h
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-mpmsk         1/1     Running       0          28h               pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xs6b7         1/1     Running       0          10h  
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-tqplz         0/1     Terminating   0          29h               pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xpmsk         1/1     Running       0          28h  
def-pods-6cbf6b8f8f-wk6pq         1/1     Running       0          27h               pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xqplz         1/1     Running       0          29h  
jklmno-pods-df6885fd9-6vqhs       0/1     Terminating   0          510d10h           pqr-pods-xcbf6b8f8f-Xk6pq         1/1     Running       0          27h  
mno-pods-df6885fd9-7dcbv          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             abcjkl-pods-xf6885fd9-RvqIs       0/1     Terminating   0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-7fh9q          1/1     Running       0          29h               jkl-pods-xf6885fd9-RdcIv          0/1     Pending       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-cch24          1/1     Running       1          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-RfhIq          1/1     Running       0          29h  
mno-pods-df6885fd9-fn7qr          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-RchI4          1/1     Running       1          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-k757b          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-Rn7Ir          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-kxwdn          1/1     Running       0          5d9h              jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-R75Ib          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-m9mq8          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-RxwIn          1/1     Running       0          5d9h 
mno-pods-df6885fd9-mnlxm          0/1     Pending       0          12h               jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-R9mI8          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-r6h68          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-RnlIm          1/1     Running       0          12h  
mno-pods-df6885fd9-s8vxk          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-R6hI8          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-splct          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-R8vIk          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-xbhcl          1/1     Running       0          29h               jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-RplIt          0/1     Pending       0          5d10h
mno-pods-df6885fd9-zr7bv          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-RbhIl          1/1     Running       0          29h  
jkl-pods-0f6885fd9-Rr7Iv          1/1     Running       0          5d10h             jkl-pods-0bc9fb4d9-R47Id          1/1     Running       0          5d10h
```

What I want: is to highlight (using SED) the "entire entry" where the 0/1 is matched.

I have already achieved the following using SED:
[image: Image 1]

What I want to achieve is:
[image: Image 2]

How can I highlight 31 characters before and after 0/1
(0/1 is included in the highlighting as already depicted in the 2nd image)

I used the following code to highlight 0/1:

```
cat /home/McFly/myPods.log | sed -ue 's/\(0\/1\)/'`printf '\033[1;31m'`'\1'`printf '\033[0m'`'/g'
```

I know this can be achieved using GREP.
I NEED to achieve it using SED.

A small problem remains with the output | `watch -n 1 --color ./myScript.sh` gives:
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use text instead of images

Comment: My bad, I have updated the question and added the minimal needed in the text form.
Thank you both for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two blocks are on the same line, and that you want to add color to the background and not the text, you can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -E s"~[a-z]+-[^/]*0/1([^0-9]*.){2}[^ ]*~$(tput setab 1)&$(tput sgr 0)~g" /home/McFly/myPods.log
```

If instead, you intend to add color to the text and not the background as your current code will do, then change `setab 1` to `setaf 1` i.e

```
$ sed -E s"~[a-z]+-[^/]*0/1([^0-9]*.){2}[^ ]*~$(tput setaf 1)&$(tput sgr 0)~g" /home/McFly/myPods.log
```

Comment: Dear Hatless, thank you so much for the response. It fulfilled the requirement well. Therefore i will accept this response as my answer.

A quick concern though:
Please see the very last screenshot in my question. Its adding "(B" in the highlighted entries randomly, thereby disturbs the the format of output. Could you address that as well please?

I am running the piece of code in watch command like this:
watch -n 1 --color ./myScript.sh

Comment: @McFly You're welcome. If the current question has been answered, please ask a new one .